# Regex that disallows " and allows \"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing to extract strings which are surrounded by quotes ("). I use the below statement in jquery to get it.

```
var item = objstr.match(/\"(([^\"])*)\"/g);
```

But i want to make an exception for \" to be allowed.

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working for you? What flavor of regex (PCRE, perl, .NET) are you using? Please edit your question to add the efforts you've made, and add the tag for the appropriate regex engine. If you provide us information, it's much more likely you'll get help (and you'll get it much faster as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex might work as well, without using look-aheads or look-behinds: (remove the spaces!)

```
/" (\\\\ | \\" | [^"])* "/
```

Read: Match a string from double-quote to double quote. In between there may be nothing or any combination of escaped backslashes `\\`, escaped double quotes `\"` or any non-quote characters. This allows for input like

```
"abc\\abc\abc\"abc\\\"abc"
```

to be valid, but not

```
"abc\\"abc"
//    ^ String terminates here
```

You might want that if your string may have the unescaped meaning `\"`.

The answer from @nickb doesn't have this feature/bug, whatever you call it. Both strings are valid in his regex.

Should your regex engine be able to turn off *backtracking*, this is the time to use it. In Perl, I have to add a `+` to a quantifier (or turn to esoteric branch resets). I don't know what you need.

```
/" (\\\\ | \\" | [^"])*+ "/
```

We also *want* greedy behaviour, so no `*?` constructs.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested following code from http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/ :

```
var s = "wwww\"ooxx\\\"xyz\"";
var foo = s.match(/"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"/);
document.write(foo[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times, and it always elicits the same obvious-but-incorrect answers.  ;)

The negative lookbehind approach --  `(?<!\\)"` -- doesn't work because it fails to account for escaped backslashes.  I know that wasn't mentioned in the question, but if the source text uses backslashes to escape quotes, you should assume unless told otherwise that it uses them to escape other backslashes, too.

The alternation approach -- `"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"` -- deals with escaped backslashes, but incorrectly.  And adding another alternative --  `"(\\\\|\\"|[^"])*"` -- doesn't fix it.  It matches valid input okay, but given a malformed string like this one:

```
"escaped \"quotes\" but no ending quote
```

...instead of reporting a failed match as it should, it incorrectly matches this:

```
"escaped \"quotes\"
```

Here's the best approach, as found in RegexBuddy's library and discussed in [The Book](http://regex.info/):

```
/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"/g
```

If the matched strings should not include line separators (like Java string literals), use this:

```
/"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"/g
```

Other approaches are possible, but this one has three major advantages: It's been proven many times over; it's extremely efficient; and it doesn't depend on advanced features--in other words, it works even in JavaScript, the red-headed stepchild of Perl-derived regex flavors. :D